# Postgres unnamed portal ID flushing

Tags: sql, postgresql

When returning result from refcursor in postgres I get following records:

```
<unnamed portal 1>
<unnamed portal 2>
...
```

We have an auto-increment for unnamed portal ID, how can I reset this ID without resetting/creating new connection (in current session)?
What I mean is I want to get this result:

```
<unnamed portal 1>
<unnamed portal 1>
<unnamed portal 1>
```

After calling:

```
select func1();
select func1();
select func1();
```

Instead of the one described above.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more what does the `func1()` exactly does to get results of `unnamed portal [N]`? Maybe share you func1() cursor code? In general, if you want to fetch/move cursor results within session execute where the exact limitation comes when [Using Cursors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html#PLPGSQL-CURSOR-USING)?

Comment: all that functions return refcursors contents:

    ...
    vrc REFCURSOR;
    ...
    RETURN vrc;

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty understandable, but what is the query run that set the value of that `vrc` ? Without seeing the function code or the query how the value is set is pretty hard to help blindly :)

Comment: Yeh, I get your point, i've got over 100 of such functions , all of them usually return different result set to the refcursor, so i have many executions of different functions and all of them return different 'unnamed portal' values, the reason why i want to reset IDs of unnamed portal is because i want to do automated testing, but because of count is often changed and result set can be different IDs change in different and even sometimes not much predictable manner:) that's why I'm looking for a simple and easy way to reset unnamed portal IDs or even the unnamed portal itself after fetching

Comment: So, just to make sure I understand correctly, those unnamed portal IDs are like serial type (sequence) IDs in DB?

Comment: Yes, they are, and are stored while session is active, what I want to get it where they are stored, and how to operate them in order to do manipulations like flushing, changing, etc. with no session reset.

Comment: Ok, I think I finally understood your case and if true then you are using automatically generated cursor names as given example in documentation (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html#AEN66597). I did try to find the answer is it possible to clear during the session temp buffer easily, but couldn't find so far any good option. So, I'm not saying it is not possible, but there doesn't seem to exist any easy/good solution for it also.